# Why is there coherence below the cutoff frequency of two high-pass filtered signals?

Tags: hilbert-transform, highpass-filter, coherence

I record surface EMG signals from two muscles at 1500 Hz. The following preprocessing steps are performed using basic MATLAB commands.

First, I decimate both signals to 500 Hz (Lowpass filtering followed by down sampling). Here, I use the default setting of the decimate command (IIR filter with cutoff frequency at 0.2667). I then High-Pass filter both signals with a 10 Hz cutoff frequency using an 8th order Butterworth filter after which I detrend the signal by subtracting the mean from each signal. Now, I calculate the Hilbert transform using the corresponding MATLAB command and then take its absolute value to obtain the envelope of each signal.

After these preprocessing steps I calculate Welch’s power spectral density with the following parameters (window size: 125 samples = 0.25s, overlap: 0, NFFT: 1024, sampling frequency: 500 Hz). When I inspect the power spectral density plot there is a strong peak around 2-3 Hz which I figure is due to the low frequency content introduced after obtaining the envelope.

My question is if I should omit high-pass filtering the signal as the envelope reintroduces frequency content below the High cutoff. I hope I provided a better description of my procedure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your high pass filter implemented?

Comment: how is your Hilbert filtering implemented? You *can* compute an analytic signal / Hilbert transform with a 0 Hz cutoff complex "passband" filter only letting through positive frequencies, but then it's unclear what this has to do with 10 Hz. Generally, you seem to assume a lot more knowledge on what your signal processing is than we actually have; for example "the general pipeline is based on current literature" tells us exactly nothing, and at least I would much rather have you actually describe what you're actually doing!

Comment: What do you mean by "rectified with a Hilbert Transform" ? Do you mean an envelope calculation ?

Comment: First of all, thank you for the responses. I apologize for not providing a clearer description. I will try to do so now. 
I record surface EMG signals from two muscles at 1500 Hz. The following preprocessing steps are performed using basic MATLAB commands.

Comment: First, I decimate both signals to 500 Hz (Lowpass filtering followed by down sampling). Here, I use the default setting of the decimate command (IIR filter with cutoff frequency at 0.2667). I then High-Pass filter both signals with a 10 Hz cutoff frequency using an 8th order Butterworth filter after which I detrend the signal by subtracting the mean from each signal. Now, I calculate the Hilbert transform using the corresponding MATLAB command and then take its absolute value to obtain the envelope of each signal.

Comment: After these preprocessing steps I calculate Welch’s power spectral density with the following parameters (window size: 125 samples = 0.25s, overlap: 0, NFFT: 1024, sampling frequency: 500 Hz). When I inspect the power spectral density plot there is a strong peak around 2-3 Hz which I figure is due to the low frequency content introduced after obtaining the envelope. 
My question is if I should omit high-pass filtering the signal as the envelope reintroduces frequency content below the High cutoff. I hope I provided a better description of my procedure.

Comment: @Tydur can you copy & paste these comments into your question – they are helpful, but will be lost here.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I copied all remarks to the edited question.

Comment: "if I should omit high-pass filtering the signal as the envelope reintroduces frequency content".  There's still not enough information in your question, because the question it raises is "is there useful information there?", and that, in turn, depends on your signal.  And _that_, in turn, depends on what an EMG measures, and whether you'd expect to see variations in the envelope at low frequencies.  Helping you with the physiological part of the question is outside the scope of this _signal processing_ stack exchange, but variations in muscle effort at around 2-3Hz could result in your signal

Comment: Ok, I understand that the physiological part is outside the scope of this forum. Still, thank you for your help !